# Windows-Charging indicator sound

Tags: windows, notifications, charger, power-options

Is there a way to make Windows play a sound when the charger is removed. In Linux i usually get sound notification when the charger is removed (a beep sound). Its very helpful to preserve the battery. Is there a built in option or do i have to make my own?

Comment: Rather than going with Batch or PowerShell, it might be worthwhile to learn some C# and use the [SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx) event to get actively notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a built in option or do i have to make my own?

Windows doesn't play any sounds when a laptop is unplugged.

You can however use the batch files below.

**Battery.cmd**

- This batch file monitors whether a laptop is currently on mains power or battery power.
- It performs the check every 10 minutes (adjust to taste).
- It will beep if the mains is unplugged and the laptop starts to use the battery.
- You need to create `beep.cmd` (see later).

  ```
  @echo off
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  :start
  rem get the battery status, 1 = battery discharging 2 = on mains
  rem use findstr to strip blank lines from wmic output

  for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%i in (`wmic path win32_battery get batterystatus ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
    set _status=%%i
    if [!_status!] equ [1] (
      rem on battery so beep
      call beep
      goto :done
      ) else (
      rem on mains
      rem wait for 10 minutes then try again
      timeout /t 600 /nobreak > nul
      goto :start
      )
    )
  :done
  endlocal
  ```

**Beep.cmd**

- This command will echo <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> which is the bel control character to make a beep.

To create beep.cmd:

1. Open a `cmd` shell
2. Enter the following commands:

   ```
   copy con beep.cmd
   @echo ^G^Z
   ```

   where ^G is <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and ^Z is <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>
3. Type the following command to test the beep:

   ```
   beep
   ```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [Using Windows PowerShell to Determine if a Laptop Is on Battery Power](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/07/31/using-windows-powershell-to-determine-if-a-laptop-is-on-battery-power/)
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: Thanks, you rock :D
I changed the timeout to 1 second and there i have what i wanted.
However the batch job exits when beep is played.

Comment: @me_alok You want it to keep beeping?

Comment: sure, my battery is dying

Comment: @me_alok Change `goto :done` to `goto :start` :)

Comment: This was the output


"main"
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
"battery"

And yes i tweaked it a bit to see what's going on

Comment: @me_alok Have you got a `:label` on a line immediately after `(`?

Comment: Bell.cmd's output
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Probably this https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/batch-file/3152/comments-in-batch-files/10745/using-labels-as-comments#t=201704230812134988479

Comment: @me_alok `Bell`? It should be `Beep`. Stop breaking working code :)

Comment: The :start label is on the begining and :done on the end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57570/discussion-between-me-alok-and-davidpostill).